# How to convert a matrix into an adjencency list in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, graph

I have an array that is representing a graph. I'd like to convert it into an adjecency list of the type `(i,j)` with `i<j` (so there is no double data). I have one problem so far:

1. I don't know how to access the array and modify it, I haven't compiled the code below yet but I'm pretty sure `list[node]->..` is not correct..

This is my code so far, without the array:

```
struct node {
    public:
        int number;
        node* next;
};

class AdjList {
    public: 
        void initialize (node* list);
        void convert (bool** array, node* list);
        void make (node*list, int number, int node);
    private:
};

void AdjList::initialize (node* list) {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        list[i]->next = NULL;
    }
}

void AdjList::make(node* list, int num, int node) {
    if (list[node]->next == NULL) {
        node* New = new node*;
        list->[node]->next = New;
        New->next = NULL;
        New->number = num;
    }
    else {
        node* New = list[node];
        while (New->next != NULL)
            New = New->next;
        node* New2 = new node*;
        New->next = New2;
        New2->number = num;
    }
}

void AdjList::convert(bool** array, node* list) {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<10; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] == true)
                make(list, j, i);
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    node* list[10];
}
```

Comment: Standard containers will make your life much, much easier. Look into `std::list`.

Comment: I would use a `std::list` with `std::pair` `typedef std::list<std::pair<int, int> > AdjList ;` Now `AdjList` is a list of pairs.

Comment: Do **not** use a `std::list`, it’s the completely wrong container here and will be very inefficient. Use `std::vector`. Furthermore, an adjacency list is actually a list of lists – i.e. a `std::vector<std::vectors<T>>`.

Comment: You're trying to do too many new things at once. You do not know how to make a linked list; tackle that first before you worry about making one out of something else.

Comment: Thanks, that's part of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll place this here, maybe it will be helpful for someone:

```
for (int i=0;i<bound;i++) {
    for (int j=i+1;j<bound;j++) {
        help = list[i];
        if (Array[i][j] == true) {
            help2 = new node;
            if (help->next == NULL) {
                help->next = help2;
                help2->number = j;
                help2->next = NULL;
            }
            else {
                while (help->next != NULL)
                    help = help->next;
                help->next = help2;
                help2->next = NULL;
                help2->number = j;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

This is how I did it.